# ngModel not working in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have been developing a simple application on Nativescript playground recently, where i found that ngModel was not working on input type TextField. I have made sure that i import NativescriptFormModule in the module of the app. but still it is not working.

Comment: Share the NativeScript Playground if you want some help. You should at least be able to use [(text)] as you would with an ngModel attribute.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Kjr9Fv&v=2

Comment: @FlorianThuin can you show me whats's wrong in the code.. (If any)

Answer (score 1):

You the extended syntax instead of ngModel (`text` and `textChange`) as the TextFuield is a complex layout with multiple bindable properties (hint, text, returnType, etc.) - example [Playground here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Kjr9Fv&v=3) and documentation article [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/text-field)

HTML

```
<TextField [hint]="hint" [text]="name" (textChange)="onTextChange($event)"></TextField>
```

TypeScript

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
    name: string;
    hint: string = "enter name";

    tf: TextField;

    onTextChange(args: EventData) { 
        console.log("onTextChange");

        this.tf = <TextField>args.object;
        console.log("tf.text: ", this.tf.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with the NativeScript Playground tutorial today. Could'nt have my [(ngModel)]="user.email" (or password) to work. I fixed it by importing the NativeScriptFormsModule and adding it to @NgModule imports in the app.module.ts

`import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";`

then

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptFormsModule]
})
```

app.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptUIChartModule } from "nativescript-ui-chart/angular";
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from "nativescript-angular/http-client";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptModule,
    NativeScriptUIChartModule,
    NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
    NativeScriptFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: he said already imported the FormModule